# Only load route with existent parametre

Tags: laravel, routes

Im doing a crud, i want to show item data using id, i have this in web.php:

```
Route::get('update/{id}', 'CrudController@update');
```

How can I deny that the user changes the id in the path to one that does not exist? That shows only those that exist and those that do not, that do not load?

Answer (score 0):

In your update method, you can do the following:

```
public function update($id)
{
    MyModel::findOrFail($id);
    //...perform other actions
}
```

It will throw a 404 response if the requested `$id` is a non-existent one.

Then you can catch it if you want in the `render()` method of `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
.
.
.
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                'data' => 'Resource not found'
            ], 404);
        } else {
           abort(404);
        }
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

---

Or, If you do not want to go through all the trouble of configuring it in the handler, you could also do:

```
public function update($id)
{
    if (! $model = MyModel::find($id)) {
        abort(404);
    }
    //...perform other actions with $model
}
```

The `abort(404)` method takes the user to the default `Page not found` page of laravel, which is an appropriate thing to do.

Comment: and if i have controller on controllers/admin/?

Comment: The controller's location has nothing to do with your problem. If you are asking how can you load a controller from subfolder, then you should do this: `Route::get('update/{id}', 'admin\CrudController@update');`

Comment: yes, but MyModel::findOrFail($id); return me he error: model not found

Comment: @c4rlosls Updated the answer.